# Pandas returning empty DF after successful merge

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

When I try to merge my two dataframes, it returns an empty DF. However, there is definitely common elements between the two join columns.

I've already tried converting the columns to the same dtype. Still, there is an empty dataframe. If I download the CSVs out and do this in Microsoft Excel or R, I receive a DF back.

```
# This column has strings and numbers, so cannot convert to int.
hierarchy_df['TargetSegmentNo'] = hierarchy_df.TargetSegmentNo.astype(str)

# target_match is a list I generated, it looks like ['4067', '4068', ...]
adhoc_df['target_match'] = target_match
adhoc_df['target_match'] = adhoc_df.target_match.astype(str)


> print(list(adhoc_df['target_match'])[0])
> print(type(list(adhoc_df['target_match'])[0]))
> print(adhoc_df.target_match.dtype)
> print(type(list(hierarchy_df['TargetSegmentNo'])[0]))
> print(hierarchy_df.TargetSegmentNo.dtype)

    <class 'str'>
    object
    <class 'str'>
    object
```

I can see that the column types match, and that elements of both are strings. I can manually see that there are elements of adhoc_df['target_match'] are in hierarchy_df['TargetSegmentNo']. However, when I do a check, it returns False.

```
> print(list(adhoc_df['target_match'])[0] in list(hierarchy_df['TargetSegmentNo']))
    > False
```

This is weird, because it's definitely in there. So when I try to merge:
    fin = adhoc_df.merge(hierarchy_df, left_on = 'target_match', right_on = 'TargetSegmentNo', how  = 'inner')

I get an empty DF as a result. Am I missing something here?

Comment: try join instead of merge.

Comment: please provide some sample data with examples to show how the `merge` is not happening